# Xamarin Forms FFImageLoading doesn't load images from a specific URL

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, ffimageloading

I'm trying to load an image from [this url](https://uploads.mangadex.org//covers/fffbfac3-b7ad-41ee-9581-b4d90ecec941/3787d628-0387-43ea-b732-3b9015584c0b.jpg.256.jpg) to `CachedImage`
unfortunately nothing is displayed.

For example, the image from [this url](http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg) is loaded fine

I followed the necessary steps from the documentation so I have all the Init in `MainActivity.cs`, etc.
I tried every solution I found here.
It shouldn't be encoded in GZIP

Also, no error message is displayed and the image is displayed correctly in `Xamarin.Forms.Image`

XAML file:

```xml
<ffimageloading:CachedImage
    Aspect="AspectFill"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    Source="{Binding Attributes.Cover256Uri}" />
```

**Edit:**

Console output:

```cs
Image memory cache size: 63.11 MB, reuse pool size:D 63.11 MB
Retry download: https://uploads.mangadex.org//covers/fffbfac3-b7ad-41ee-9581-b4d90ecec941/3787d628-0387-43ea-b732-3b9015584c0b.jpg.256.jpg
Retry download: https://uploads.mangadex.org//covers/fffbfac3-b7ad-41ee-9581-b4d90ecec941/3787d628-0387-43ea-b732-3b9015584c0b.jpg.256.jpg
Retry download: https://uploads.mangadex.org//covers/fffbfac3-b7ad-41ee-9581-b4d90ecec941/3787d628-0387-43ea-b732-3b9015584c0b.jpg.256.jpg
Retry download: https://uploads.mangadex.org//covers/fffbfac3-b7ad-41ee-9581-b4d90ecec941/3787d628-0387-43ea-b732-3b9015584c0b.jpg.256.jpg

FFImageLoading.Exceptions.DownloadAggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.) (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.) (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.) (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.) ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
  at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132
  at Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsContext.ProcessHandshake () [0x00042] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Btls/MonoBtlsContext.cs:220 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status, System.Boolean renegotiate) [0x000da] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MobileAuthenticatedStream.cs:715 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake(Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus,bool)
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncHandshakeRequest.Run (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/AsyncProtocolRequest.cs:289 
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000fc] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/AsyncProtocolRequest.cs:223 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessAuthentication (System.Boolean runSynchronously, Mono.Net.Security.MonoSslAuthenticationOptions options, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0025c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MobileAuthenticatedStream.cs:310 
  at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Net.Security.SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0007b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/ConnectHelper.cs:165 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Net.Security.SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000f6] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/ConnectHelper.cs:176 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x002d8] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:408 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync (System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult] creationTask) [0x000a2] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:543 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0003f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:284 
  at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00070] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/RedirectHandler.cs:32 
  at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00080] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/DecompressionHandler.cs:48 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x000b3] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:531 
  at FFImageLoading.Cache.DownloadCache.DownloadAsync (System.String url, System.Threading.CancellationToken token, System.Net.Http.HttpClient client, FFImageLoading.Work.TaskParameter parameters, FFImageLoading.DownloadInformation downloadInformation) [0x00142] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Cache\DownloadCache.cs:107 
  at FFImageLoading.Cache.DownloadCache+<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<DownloadAndCacheIfNeededAsync>b__0 () [0x00050] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Cache\DownloadCache.cs:58 
  at FFImageLoading.Retry.DoAsync[T] (System.Func`1[TResult] action, System.TimeSpan retryInterval, System.Int32 retryCount, System.Action onRetry) [0x00047] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Helpers\Retry.cs:19 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at FFImageLoading.Retry.DoAsync[T] (System.Func`1[TResult] action, System.TimeSpan retryInterval, System.Int32 retryCount, System.Action onRetry) [0x0023b] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Helpers\Retry.cs:65 
  at FFImageLoading.Cache.DownloadCache.DownloadAndCacheIfNeededAsync (System.String url, FFImageLoading.Work.TaskParameter parameters, FFImageLoading.Config.Configuration configuration, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00401] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Cache\DownloadCache.cs:57 
  at FFImageLoading.DataResolvers.UrlDataResolver.Resolve (System.String identifier, FFImageLoading.Work.TaskParameter parameters, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00045] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\DataResolvers\UrlDataResolver.cs:22 
  at FFImageLoading.DataResolvers.WrappedDataResolver.Resolve (System.String identifier, FFImageLoading.Work.TaskParameter parameters, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0004e] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\DataResolvers\WrappedDataResolver.cs:21 
  at FFImageLoading.Work.ImageLoaderTask`3[TDecoderContainer,TImageContainer,TImageView].RunAsync () [0x00300] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Work\ImageLoaderTask.cs:618
```

So FFImageLoading is failing to load HTTPS images because the intermediate certificate issued by provider has expired.

So I provide my own instance of HttpClient (that has SSL bypass in its handler) on the MainPange.xaml.cs file by using ImageService.

```cs
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = 
                (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) => true;

_httpClient = new HttpClient(handler); 

var config = new FFImageLoading.Config.Configuration()
{
    ...
    HttpClient = _httpClient,
    ...
};
```

Source: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/1448#issuecomment-941728729

Comment: enable verbose logging - https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/blob/master/source/FFImageLoading.Common/Config/Configuration.cs